# Problems creating new File in Java

Tags: java, file

I Have a function that receives a `File`, when i put `new File("filepath")` in the arguments it works, but when try to use `new File(string)` it returns `Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException`. Also i tested if the strings are equal and the test returns true.

Here is part of my code:

```
System.out.println(filev.getPath());
String str = filev.getPath();
str = str.replace("\\", "/");
System.out.println(str);
if(str.equals("D:/POO/TF_V2_7/account_info/1234567890989.csv")) {
    System.out.println("EQUALS");
}
Account acc = Account.newAccount(new File(str)); // Returns InputMismatchException
Account acc = Account.newAccount(new File("D:/POO/TF_V2_7/account_info/1234567890989.csv")); // Runs well
```

P.S. In the `newAccount()` function the file is read with a `Scanner`.

Comment: if you could rewrite this as a question, it'd be more helpful. Are you asking what an InputMismatchException is?

Comment: @jk. no, im asking why when i give a `String` it wont work but when a give a `String` like `"D:/POO/TF_V2_7/account_info/1234567890989.csv"` it works?

P.S. Sorry my english

Comment: I tested and works as expected. Looks like your `str` String has an *odd* character in it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza but if it really had an odd character `.equals()` wont return true

Comment: Your odd char may be in your `String` as well. At least I cannot reproduce this error on my pc. You should add more info about this problem, like Java version, exact OS name, and such.

Comment: Also, make sure that you're providing the necessary code to reproduce the problem. From [`java.util.InputMismatchException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html): *Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.*

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Maybe this can help.
This is when i give the `str` http://prntscr.com/3j6nx3 
This is when i give `"D:/POO/TF_V2_7/account_info/1234567890989.csv"` http://prntscr.com/3j6o3q

Comment: Two things: 1) you should not post an image of your stacktrace, but post the stacktrace content right into the question. 2) The error appears inside `Account.newAccount` method, which means you're using the `Scanner` in the wrong way.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza even when i compare the two files created by diferent ways - they are equal. I dont understand why with one file in works, but with other exactlly equal it wont

Comment: Me neither. This remains as a complete mystery =\ (and I'm not joking).

Comment: Can you show us the outputs of your console?